# How to reference an existing storage accounts in an ARM template of a function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I want to create a function app with an ARM template such that the ARM template references existing storage accounts ("onestoragebo" in this template), instead of creating new ones. storage. I'm getting the following error while deploying below ARM template. please help!!

***InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template reference 'onestoragebo' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.***

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "baseName": {
        "defaultValue": "func",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name use as base-template to named the resources deployed in Azure."
        }
    },
    "funcname": {
        "defaultValue": "projectitemedited",
       "type": "string",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "description"
        }
    },
    "storageaccountname": {
        "defaultValue": "onestoragebo",
       "type": "string",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "description"
        }
    }
    
    
},
"variables": {
    "suffix": "[toLower(resourceGroup().name)]",
    "funcAppName": "[toLower(concat(parameters('baseName'),'-', variables('suffix'), '-', parameters('funcname')))]",
    "serverFarmName": "[concat('plan', '-', variables('suffix'), '-', substring(parameters('funcname'), 0, min(length(parameters('funcname')),16)))]",
    "appInsightsName": "[toLower(concat('appi','-', variables('suffix'),'-', parameters('funcname')))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[variables('funcAppName')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('serverFarmName'))]",
            "[parameters('storageaccountname')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serverFarmName'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageaccountname'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('storageaccountname'),'2019-06-01').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageaccountname'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('storageaccountname'),'2019-06-01').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageaccountname'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('storageaccountname'),'2019-06-01').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                        "value": "[variables('funcAppName')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                        "value": "powershell"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                    }
                    
                ]
            },
            "httpsOnly": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(variables('funcAppName'), '/web')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('funcAppName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly"
        }
    },
    
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
            "tier": "Dynamic"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
            "computeMode": "Dynamic"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
        "kind": "web",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('funcAppName'))]": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "Application_Type": "web",
            "ApplicationId": "[variables('appInsightsName')]"
        }
    }
    
    
],
"outputs": {
    "functionappname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('funcAppName')]"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to deploy the function app with an existing storage account by adding ***"mode":"Incremental"*** property in the storage account resource. The new ARM file is attached. If anyone knows a better solution, please comment.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "baseName": {
        "defaultValue": "func",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name use as base-template to named the resources deployed in Azure."
        }
    },
    "funcname": {
        "defaultValue": "projectitemadded",
       "type": "string",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "description"
        }
    }
    
},
"variables": {
    "suffix": "[toLower(resourceGroup().name)]",
    "funcAppName": "[toLower(concat(parameters('baseName'),'-', variables('suffix'), '-', parameters('funcname')))]",
    "funcStorageName": "[tolower(concat('st', substring(variables('suffix'), 0, min(length(variables('suffix')),16))))]",
    "serverFarmName": "[concat('plan', '-', variables('suffix'), '-', substring(parameters('funcname'), 0, min(length(parameters('funcname')),16)))]",
    "appInsightsName": "[toLower(concat('appi','-', variables('suffix'),'-', parameters('funcname')))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('funcAppName')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('serverFarmName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('funcStorageName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serverFarmName'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('funcStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('funcStorageName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('funcStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('funcStorageName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('funcStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('funcStorageName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                        "value": "[variables('funcAppName')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                        "value": "powershell"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                    }
                    
                ]
            },
            "httpsOnly": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(variables('funcAppName'), '/web')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('funcAppName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
        "name": "[variables('funcStorageName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "funStorageName"
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
            "mode":"Incremental"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
            "tier": "Dynamic"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
            "computeMode": "Dynamic"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
        "kind": "web",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('funcAppName'))]": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "Application_Type": "web",
            "ApplicationId": "[variables('appInsightsName')]"
        }
    }
    
    
],
"outputs": {
    "functionappname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('funcAppName')]"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `dependsOn` block, you're referring to the `storageAccountName` parameter. There's no need to do that. The storage account name already exists, per your question. You can't depend on a resource that isn't defined in the ARM template. `dependsOn` exists to make sure that resources are created in the correct order.

Think about it logically: If the resource isn't defined in the template, what's it going to do if the resource doesn't exist? It can't wait for the resource to be created, because there's nothing telling the ARM template how to create it.

```
 "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('serverFarmName'))]"
    ],
```

You're also using `listKeys`. Refer to the `listKeys` documentation; when the resource isn't defined in the same template, you have to use the resource ID, not the resource name.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected the dependsOn block. But it wasn't working even without dependsOn.  I have removed it but still, the storage account is not recognized in ARM deployment.

Comment: You're also using `listKeys`. Refer to the `listKeys` documentation; when the resource isn't defined in the same template, you have to use the resource ID, not the resource name.